# RichTextBox Comparing Fonts Fail

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox

When comparing fonts in a Visual Studio 2017 C# RichTextBox, Why do the full font comparisons fail? - I've included failing [if statement] code followed by passing [if statement] code. I'm guessing this is a [Strongly Typed] issue in the UI or compiler, but I'd like some clarity. thx

```
        RichTextBox testMemo = new RichTextBox();
        testMemo.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);

        Font testFont = new Font("Calibri", 12);
```

// these all fail

```
        if (memo1.Font != testMemo.Font)
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
        }
        else
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Courier", 12);
        }

        if (memo1.Font != testFont)
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
        }
        else
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Courier", 12);
        }

        if (memo1.Font.FontFamily != testMemo.Font.FontFamily)
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
        }
        else
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Courier", 12);
        }

        if (memo1.Font.FontFamily != testFont.FontFamily)
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
        }
        else
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Courier", 12);
        }
```

// These work correctly

```
        if (memo1.Font.Name != testMemo.Font.Name && memo1.Font.SizeInPoints != testMemo.Font.SizeInPoints)
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
        }
        else
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Courier", 12);
        }

        if (memo1.Font.Name != testFont.Name && memo1.Font.SizeInPoints != testFont.SizeInPoints)
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);
        }
        else
        {
            memo1.Font = new Font("Courier", 12);
        }
```

Comment: write a single extension method and compare with both font-family and font size.

Comment: Good suggestion, though I feel like that should be built-in for font to font comparison

Comment: Because `Font` is a reference type. So you need to compare all relevant properties, as suggested..

Comment: You did notice where the FontFamily comparison fails, right?

Answer (score 0):

What about Font.Equals method ?
Instead of

```
memo1.Font != testMemo.Font
```

You would have

```
Dim fnttestMemo As Font = testMemo.Font
Dim fntMemo1 As Font = memo1.Font
If fnttestMemo.Equals(fntMemo1) = False Then
...
End If
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.equals?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0